# (Fundamental) difference of Seebeck effect for metals and semiconductors

Tags: thermodynamics, semiconductor-physics, metals, thermoelectricity

In which way is the Seebeck effect different for semiconductors from metals and why is it greater? What is the difference in the underlying physical principle?

My knowledge so far is: Bring two materials in touch, doesn't matter which, their electrochemical potentials will align but the electrical potentials will differ which causes the generating voltage.
I don't see how semiconductors are different here as it seems to be a very general principle.

Comment: Your knowledge is wrong: the Seebeck effect does not depend on whether you have two materials or not. The thermoelectric voltage is distributed along the whole conductor, where there is a temperature gradient: it's a bulk effect. Different materials or, more generally, inhomogeneities along the circuit make the effect _observable_, but it does exist even in a homogeneous material.

Comment: isn't that the thomson effect?

Comment: No, really. Pay attention that there are many books out there, especially at the elementary level, that give a wrong description and explanation of the Seebeck effect, and of all the thermoelectric effects in general (something I discussed [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/48228/20058)). Sorry I don't have time to write an extensive answer.

Comment: But I didn't say the seebeck effect is a result of contact potential.

Comment: I would word it differently than Massimo. He is right that the Seebeck effect needs no pair of materials. A single chunk of metal would do, as long as there is a temperature gradient through it (i.e. apply a temperature difference between two points). If you want to measure the Seebeck voltage and be able to read anything different from 0V, then you will need to use a different material as probe. But the Seebeck effect takes place in a single material.

Comment: The Thomson effect is a different thing, it is a generation or absorption of heat through the material (its volume) where both a temperature gradient and a current coexist. So it can locally raise or lower temperature. The usual Thomson effect exists because S depends on temperature. However an analogous effect takes place if S depends on x (for example an inhomogeneous doping), though people named the effect distributed Peltier effect or extrinsic Thomson effect. There are other similar effects (some have names, others don't, yet), when S varies because of other thermodynamics variables.

Comment: All of them have the same end result, a local heat/cooling of the material.
In fact there is a single "thermoelectric effect" which is an entanglement between electricity and the thermal gradient. It can have a lot of different manifestations, including what is called as Seebeck effect, Peltier effect, Thomson effect, etc. (there are more effects less known, I suggest you dig into it if you're interested).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer has to do with the relation between the Seebeck coefficient and the electrical conductivity's dependence on energy, known as the Mott Formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermopower#Mott_formula).

In short, the model that leads to the formula yields to a Seebeck coefficient that is proportional to -T for metals, with a very small factor (proportional to $T/T_F$ where the Fermi temperature is much bigger than the absolute temperature) and so yields low values.

However for semiconductors, one has to check the band structures according to the doping level and again how the electrical conductivity depends on the energy. It turns out that the prefactors in the different Mott formulae are not as small as in the case of a metal, apparently because transport does not occur near the Fermi level in this case.

Comment: Thank you! But would you say it is a different principle then?

Comment: I would say it is the same principle, generally. The big difference lies in the energy dependence of the conductivity because the density of states of the charge carriers differ greatly between metals and semiconductors.

Comment: Thanks for clearifying!